# Using .get() in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I know that in Python I can use `Dictionary["Key"]` to get the value. This has a downside that there is no fallback value if key is not found.

The method `Dictionary.get("Key", "FallbackString")` allows for a fallback which is what I need.

In Jinja2 I know I can use the first method but how can I use `.get()` in Jinja2?

Current Jinja2 code:

```
{{ Dictionary["Key"] }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully, Jinja2 is python in a sense -- use your python .get directly:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from jinja2 import Template

templatestr = '''Name: {{ name.get('key', 'unknown') }}'''

print(Template(templatestr).render(name={ 'key': 'Bob' }))
print(Template(templatestr).render(name={ }))
```